# Date and Time zone

Tags: javascript, ruby

I am trying to share date/time between JavaScript and Ruby. I get buggy results because of timezone. I tried many combinations without success. I tried the following. Let us say I have a date in JavaScript:

```
planning_schedule.getState().min_date
Mon Apr 23 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

I need to share it with `wait`. So I tried:

```
planning_schedule.getState().min_date.toISOString()
"2018-04-22T22:00:00.000Z"
```

or

```
planning_schedule.getState().min_date.toUTCString();
"Sun, 22 Apr 2018 22:00:00 GMT"
```

In Rails, I do:

```
start_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:current_date1], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z')
start_week = start_date.at_beginning_of_week
end_week = start_date.at_end_of_week
```

and I get as result:

```
start_date #=> Sun, 22 Apr 2018 22:00:00 +0000 (should be monday 23)
start_week #=> Mon, 16 Apr 2018 00:00:00 +0000 (so everything is shifted)
end_week #=> Sun, 22 Apr 2018 23:59:59 +0000
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question : what is the "good" way to share DateTime info between Javascript and rails, using this technic I lose the timezone shift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toISOString` is a good start because it gives you a [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant string representation.

Ruby can parse such string via [`Time.iso8601`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-iso8601):

```
Time.iso8601('2018-04-22T22:00:00.000Z')
#=> 2018-04-22 22:00:00 UTC
```

which can be converted to your system's timezone via [`localtime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Time.html#method-i-localtime):

```
Time.iso8601('2018-04-22T22:00:00.000Z').localtime
#=> 2018-04-23 00:00:00 +0200
```

Rails has more sophisticated timezone support:

```
Time.iso8601('2018-04-22T22:00:00.000Z').in_time_zone
#=> Mon, 23 Apr 2018 00:00:00 CEST +02:00

Time.zone.iso8601('2018-04-22T22:00:00.000Z')
#=> Mon, 23 Apr 2018 00:00:00 CEST +02:00
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, it's exacly what I was looking for